# Run errors: N-by-N Checkerboard

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Checkerboard {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
      Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
      int n = Keyboard.nextInt();
      int col = n;

    int size = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );




            if ( n % 2 == 0 ) {

                for ( size = 0; size < n; size++ ) {

                    System.out.print("* ");

                }

            }

            else {
                 for ( size = 1; size < n; size++ )

                    System.out.print("* ");

                    System.out.println();

                 }



        }  

    }
```

The Assignment: Write a program named Checkerboard.java that prompts the user running it for one integer value N. The Program outputs a two dimensional N-by-N checkerboard pattern with alternating spaces and asterisks. 
For N=4

---

---

---

---

My problem: The code compiles but does not run!

```
The errors: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Checkerboard.main(Checkerboard.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

> 

Okay, I would really appreciate some help with this. I have no idea if the code I have would even do what I want to do... ughhhh frustrating.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: learn to format your code in an IDE before pasting it here, you will get as much effort in the answers as you put into making your question

Comment: it is failing on `args[0]`, unless you are passing something into `int size = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );` by default `args[]` doesn't hold anything.

Comment: I'd comment this line out: `int size = Integer.parseInt( args[0] );` and then declare size as int in the for loops and then run it

Comment: @ryekayo - if they just comment out that line, it won't compile because `size` is used below.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, I made a quick edit to my comment to fix what you mentioned :)

Comment: Thank you both. It runs now, but it does not display what I want. I guess I'm one step closer though.